# Using RQuantLib in Java with RJava

Tags: java, r, rjava

i'm relatively new to using RJava and was getting a null pointer exception from a piece of code I was trying out. I suspect that this could be due to the data type I am using, but am a bit confused about how to solve this. Any help with this would be amazing.

```
    import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;



    public class RJava {

    public static void main(String a[]) {


        String javaVector = "c(put, 0.0425, 66.592, 66.00, 0, 0.068, 0.072, 0.1)";


        Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);


        engine.eval("library(RQuantLib)");
        engine.eval("rVector=" + javaVector);
        engine.eval("Euvol=EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(rVector)");

        double vol = engine.eval("Euvol").asDouble();
        System.out.println("Vol=" + vol);

    }
}

       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at co.karan.RJava.main(RJava.java:49)
```

Comment: What dependency jar(s) are used by your project, which contain class org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine?

Comment: i've got JRI.jar, JRIEngine.jar, and REngine.jar.

Comment: I believe it is part of rJava 0.9-8, so it is the current release of JRI which is 0.5-0. I hope I interpreted your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a null exception and it happens in `RJava`, have you tried to use a debugger to figure out where exactly it crashes?

Your code can't crash in `javaVector` and `new Rengine` because the Java runtime guarantees it'll throw an exception but it won't be a null exception. Your code also can't crash in your `eval` calls. So what else?

Your code crashes in `engine.eval("Euvol")`. The function `eval` gives you a null and you try to cast to double, you can't do this.

Now, you should think why your R engine gave you a null exception. There're several possibilities:

**1**: You don't have QuantLib installed. RQuantLib won't work if your QuantLib is not properly installed. Worse, you might not even have RQuantLib installed.

**2**: Your inputs to RQuanlib are not correct. Read the documentation:

[image]

The first argument is a **STRING**. In your code you gave `put`, this is a **variable** but not a string.

The R vector `c(put, 0.0425, 66.592, 66.00, 0, 0.068, 0.072, 0.1)` is invalid. Try to copy it to your R and you'll get an error.